# Rellenar nan valus con un diccionario en pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe que una columna es del tipo object, algunos registros tienen diccionarios y otros Nan.
Cuando ejecuto el codigo:

```
jobs_df["location"] = jobs_df["location"].fillna("Probando")
```

Funciona correctamente. Pero si quiero rellenar los Nan con un diccionario, solo lo ignora y no funciona.

```
jobs_df["location"] = jobs_df["location"].fillna({'country': ''})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuándo envías un diccionario, [la documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) explica que lo usa para encontrar el valor a usar para cada índice. Quizás puedas enviar un diccionario con el diccionario como valor. Algo como `{'location': {'country': ''}}` No tengo los medios ni el tiempo para probar ahora mismo que funcione, y tu pregunta no incluye código que pueda usar para probarlo, pero es probable.

Comment: @jachguate buena idea! pero una aclaración y un problema: para poder aplicarla, habría que usar fillna en el df (df.fillna) en lugar de df["location"].fillna. Además, eso no resuelve la segunda problematica (que al usar fillna habría varios valores haciendo referencia al mismo diccionario, el cual no se copia)

Comment: Tu idea no me funciona, no me reemplaza los NA. Supongo que los subdiccionarios también significan algo.

Comment: Dante, es muy cierto lo que dices, pero lo segundo puede o no ser problema, dependiendo del uso que el AP quiera dar al DF, particularmente a ese valor.

Comment: Si no piensa modificar los diccionarios, seguro no va a ser un problema. Pero al menos es un detalle que se debe tener muy presente, así buscás otro camino a la hora de querer modificar los diccionarios.

Answer (score 1):

#### Causa

El error tiene una causa muy curiosa. Si leemos [la documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) de Pandas sobre este argumento:

> Value to use to fill holes (e.g. 0), alternately a
> dict/Series/DataFrame of values specifying which value to use for each
> index (for a Series) or column (for a DataFrame). Values not in the
> dict/Series/DataFrame will not be filled. This value cannot be a list.

Que con mi vago inglés y el traductor de Google (cualquier edición es bienvenida) sería:

> Valor a usar para llenar agujeros (por ejemplo, 0), alternativamente
> un dict/Series/DataFrame de valores que especifican qué valor usar
> para cada índice (para una Serie) o columna (para un DataFrame). Los
> valores que no estén en dict/Series/DataFrame no se completarán. Este
> valor no puede ser una lista.

Vemos que nos indica que el diccionario no se está tratando como un escalar normal. Pandas intenta reemplazar todos los valores de la serie que son NaN y cuyo indice está en el diccionario. Y no encuentra nada, haciendo que no haya cambios.

#### Un aviso sobre lo que intentas hacer

Incluso si no te hubieras topado con este problema, te hubieses encontrado con otro. Modificar uno de los diccionarios que reemplazaste afectaría a todos los diccionarios que fueron producto del reemplazo. Esto se debe a que en realidad Pandas no copia el diccionario y realmente cada valor haría referencia al mismo diccionario.

Por supuesto, como dice Jachguate, si no pensás modificar los diccionarios, esto no será un problema, pero diría que hay que tenerlo muy presente e, incluso, aclararlo en forma de comentario para que ningún desarrollador futuro choque con el problema.

Demostración utilizando dp.where (una alternativa más flexible a fillna)

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Al multiplicar listas, los valores no se copian
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.NA] * 10)

df[0] = df[0].where(pd.notna, lambda x:{})

print("ANTES")
print(df)

df.iloc[0][0]["hola"] = "mundo"

print("DESPUES")
print(df)
```

Resultado

```
ANTES
    0
0  {}
1  {}
2  {}
3  {}
4  {}
5  {}
6  {}
7  {}
8  {}
9  {}
DESPUES
                   0
0  {'hola': 'mundo'}
1  {'hola': 'mundo'}
2  {'hola': 'mundo'}
3  {'hola': 'mundo'}
4  {'hola': 'mundo'}
5  {'hola': 'mundo'}
6  {'hola': 'mundo'}
7  {'hola': 'mundo'}
8  {'hola': 'mundo'}
9  {'hola': 'mundo'}
```

#### Solución

Para copiar un diccionario podés usar dct.copy(), que copia el diccionario, pero no su contenido (lo cual no es un problema si el contenido del diccionario es inmutable (como cadenas o tuplas)). Pero si necesitás copiar el contenido, podés usar `deepcopy` del modulo copy.

Ya tenemos la función, ahora como la utilizamos?

Un reemplazo a `fillna` es `pd.where`, pero, descubrí que incluso si se le pasa un llamable (por ejemplo, lambda) no lo llama por cada item de la serie, si no una vez y lo reutiliza.

Pareciera, y por lo que vi en internet, que la alternativa más sencilla para matar ambos pajaros de un tiro es usar `apply`.

```
import pandas as pd
import copy

dct = {}

serie = pd.Series([pd.NA, pd.NA, 1, pd.NA])
serie = serie.apply(lambda x:copy.deepcopy(dct) if pd.isna(x) else x)

serie.iloc[1]["hola"] = "mundo"

print(serie)
```

#### Una alternativa al uso de diccionarios

La respuesta de [pythonista_entusiasta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/596725/158880) indica que usar diccionario como valor de una serie ha caido en desuso y no es recomendado.

Si ese es el caso, una buena alternativa es el [formato json](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/json.html), que:

- Se parsea con la librería estandar a travéz del modulo `json` usando una tabla de equivalencias que crea diccionarios y listas
- Muchos objetos json se parecen en comportamiento y sintaxis a los de Python, lo cual los hace facil de entender para quien ya tiene conceptos de Python incorporados
- Se pueden guardar en un dataframe en formas de cadenas, eliminando la necesitad de copiar.
- Unica desventaja: Requiere un poco de código extra para trabajarlo junto a pandas.

Un ejemplo de código usando json:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

serie = pd.Series(["{}", "{}", 1, "{}"])

dct = json.loads(serie.iloc[1])
dct["hola"] = "mundo"
serie.iloc[1] = json.dumps(dct)

print(serie)
```

Answer (score 1):

Aprovechando la utilidad de las IA, Google bard me sugirio esta respuesta y funciono:

```
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['{"city": "London", "country": "UK"}', '{city: "New York", country: "US"}']})

# Convert the string in form of dictionary to dictionary type
def convert_string_to_dict(string):
    if type(string) == str:
        return json.loads(string)
    else:
        return string

df['location'] = df['location'].apply(convert_string_to_dict)

print(df)
```

Comment: Genial! Solo cambiaria `type(string) == str` por  `isinstance(string, str)`. Esto es ya que la primera, si bien, puede funcionar, no es recomendada (PEP08).

Comment: Chatgpt está prohibido, pero esa prohibicion probablemente aplica a toda ia.

Answer (score 0):

me parece que es porque se esta llamando mal el metodo.

`fillna` con un dictionario lo que hace es llenar la columna nombrada con el valor mencionado:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     'LOCATION': [None]*3,
     'COUNTRY': ['ABC','BCD','CDE']
     }
    )
df.fillna({'COUNTRY':''}) #Llena la columna COUNTRY con un ''
df.fillna({'LOCATION':''}) #Llena la columna LOCATION con un ''
```

Ahora, viendo el ejemplo, me parece que lo que se quiere lograr es llenar las columnas vacias con un dictionario. En las versionas mas recientes de pandas, esto ha caido en desuso y puede causar error (me parece que en este caso es una version previa de pandas), por lo que recomendaria mejor usar un str en este caso.

Espero sea de ayuda.